# Why is the Serpent the most common motif as the creator in indigenous Australian cultures?

Tags: creation, symbolism, indigenous-australian

Related to the question [How long ago was the Dreaming?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/109/how-long-ago-was-the-dreaming), according to the Wikipedia [Rainbow Serpent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_Serpent) page, the Rainbow Serpent is an integral part of many indigenous Australian cultures, and specifically

> The most common motif in Rainbow Serpent stories is the Serpent as creator, with the Serpent often bringing life to an empty space

**Why is the Serpent the most common motif as the creator in indigenous Australian cultures?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, I took a look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_Serpent#Possible_origins_in_nature). It explains that the Rainbow Serpent may have been inspired by one or more of the following Australian snakes:

- The rough-scaled python
- The taipan
- The file snake

These snakes could inspire cultures across the continent. Research tells me that the rough-scaled python is active in a small area of [Western Australia](http://www.arod.com.au/arod/reptilia/Squamata/Pythonidae/Morelia/carinata), though its range may be much larger. The taipan lives [in central Australia](http://inlandtaipan.weebly.com/habitat.html) as well as [the coast](http://www.ozanimals.com/Reptile/Coastal-Taipan/Oxyuranus/scutellatus%20.html) and [regions beyond](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/580808/taipan). File snakes live in [aquatic areas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acrochordidae) [across the region](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1563896?uid=3739808&uid=391386151&uid=2&uid=3&uid=3739256&uid=60&sid=21106716459113). An extinct snake, *Wonambia*, would also have lived [in the plains](http://dinosaurs.about.com/od/predinosaurreptiles/p/Wonambi.htm); [other large species](http://www.prehistoric-wildlife.com/species/w/wonambi.html) existed. Given the geographic spread of these snakes, they all could have inspired cultures across Australia.

I independently found [one of the Wikipedia sources](http://education.nationalgeographic.com/education/media/rainbow-serpent/?ar_a=1), which supports the conclusions (of course!), as well as [a related document](http://media.education.nationalgeographic.com:8080/assets/reference/assets/rainbow-serpent-1.pdf). [This](http://www.abc.net.au/radionational/programs/breakfast/saving-the-rainbow-serpent/6407852) is the only other non-National Geographic source I could find. The evidence, though, stacks up to give a sensible conclusion: Snakes were everywhere in Australia, so they provided a common habitat component. And the big ones sure seemed powerful.

One issue with this hypothesis is that some of the snakes have small geographic distributions - just look at the range of the rough-scaled python! There are other species of snakes in Australia, so they could make up the difference, but the limits of the three given snakes are a tad worrisome.

---

<sup>[A related page.](http://www.bom.gov.au/iwk/climate_culture/rainbow_serp.shtml)</sup>

Comment: Actually, the differences in snake distribution would actually go a long way in explaining differences that each Serpent creation myth has.

Answer (score 2):

The snake as a symbol for creation is common across many cultures mythologies. The mythologist [Joseph Campbell pointed out](http://sunrec.tumblr.com/post/49042928209/excerpt-from-the-power-of-myth-by-joseph) that

> The serpent sheds its skin to be born again ... it  lives by killing and eating itself, casting off death and being reborn, like the moon

Answer (score -2):

Snakes have long been associated with fertility and the subtle creative force across many cultures. Their counterpart was often the bull who stood for active virility.

Comment: The counterpart to a snake in Australia is very unlikely to be a bull. It is not an indegenous animal.